# Karate Framework version 0.9.6 onwards are missing from repo- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Tags: karate

I am getting following error when trying to update pom
Could not find artifact com.intuit.karate:karate.archetype:pom:1.0.0 in my-repo1 (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Problem is Karate latest version is not available under this repor -https://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Please suggest and my organization only this url (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) is open for maven under citrix

Comment: no one has ever reported this - so it must be some problem at your end. karate is available in maven central, here is proof: https://central.sonatype.com/search?q=karate - if some URLs are blocked, maybe you can use the VS code plugin, because it includes karate automatically: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karatelabs.karate